# How to set up visual-studio-code to display the cursor as a pointer instead of a hand?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In visual-studio-code, when the cursor hovers over dropdown menus, the left sidebar, and tab pages, it is displayed as a hand shape, which feels uncomfortable for me. As a desktop software rather than a web page, the cursor's shape doesn't seem to adhere to standard conventions.

How to set up VSCode to display the cursor as a pointer instead of a hand when hovering over tab pages, the left sidebar, and dropdown menus?

Comment: "As a desktop software rather than a web page" - seeing that VS Code is Electron based, it makes sense that it works this way.  But regardless, I don't think there is a way to change this via any settings.

Comment: would it be possible for you to show cropped screenshots with the mouse? also, I'm not aware of this being possible with vanilla VS Code, but possibly with extensions.